# HTTP status: 404 - Java Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

This may be a very small problem but still I am not able to find the solution.
I am using Apace Tomcat 7.0.54 with JAVA 1.7

I am getting the following error in the webpage in which I created a html page and added a servlet name and URL mapping to the web.xml

```
 Error message:
 HTTP Status 404 - /sayhello/
 type Status report
 message /sayhello/
 description The requested resource is not available.
```

The following is my JAVA Code.

```
// To save as "<TOMCAT_HOME>\webapps\hello\WEB-INF\classes\HelloServlet.java"
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
   @Override
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         throws IOException, ServletException {

      // Set the response MIME type of the response message
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      // Allocate a output writer to write the response message into the network socket
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

      // Write the response message, in an HTML page
      try {
         out.println("<html>");
         out.println("<head><title>Hello, World</title></head>");
         out.println("<body>");
         out.println("<h1>Hello, world!</h1>");  // says Hello
         // Echo client's request information
         out.println("<p>Request URI: " + request.getRequestURI() + "</p>");
         out.println("<p>Protocol: " + request.getProtocol() + "</p>");
         out.println("<p>PathInfo: " + request.getPathInfo() + "</p>");
         out.println("<p>Remote Address: " + request.getRemoteAddr() + "</p>");
         // Generate a random number upon each request
         out.println("<p>A Random Number: <strong>" + Math.random() + "</strong></p>");
         out.println("</body></html>");
      } finally {
         out.close();  // Always close the output writer
      }
   }
}
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

   <!-- To save as "hello\WEB-INF\web.xml" -->

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>HelloServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <!-- Note: All <servlet> elements MUST be grouped together and
         placed IN FRONT of the <servlet-mapping> elements -->

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/sayhello</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

What should be corrected here? One more thing, I tried executing another JAVA database servlet too. It also didn't return anything and gave me the same error.

Comment: Try opening "/sayhello" instead of "/sayhello/".

Comment: Same Error. One more thing, I tried executing another JAVA database servlet too. It also didn't return anything

Comment: If you are having the servlet class in some package then in servlet-class tag give the package-name.classname

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - What does "/sayhello/" mean ? That is, how does the browser interpret it ?

Comment: You have the servlet-mapping in your xml and as annotation. Remove one of them.

Comment: The server interprets it as a path.

Comment: @alkis - Yes I removed them and tried still the same error. Actually I tried that after it didn't work and forgot to copy the latest code. I have edited the question now.

Comment: your url pattern is wrong. just put /HelloServlet instead of "/sayhello" okey try it

Comment: @goutam, what url did you put in the address bar? Can you see the Apache Home Page by this url: `http://localhost:8080/`?

Comment: @Krishna - I tried /HelloServlet. I think /sayhello is supposed to work

Comment: @Arvind - Yes. The url I used is http://localhost:8080/sayhello. I can see the Apache homepage

Comment: @goutam it wont work because into the servlet Case u need to provide urlpattern as that name that which HttpServlet Action means that servlet will be called that time. u can not give other as url pattern.

Comment: you are missing the context path http://localhost:8080/hello/sayhello where /hello is the context path of your app, since thats the name of your project/folder.

Comment: @goutam, what is project name?

Comment: @EdwardM.B. may be according to me that is wrong because there is not prob of path. because he is mapping the action wrong. that is why may be prob is there

Comment: @Krishna well its 2 problems then, cause every request needs a context path which tells the web container which app its from. (thats how tomcat works by default)

Comment: where does your HelloServlet reside in the src folder or src/something folder?

Comment: @Krishna btw, you can have a different urlpattern, it doesnt have to be the name of the actual servlet.. thats the point of the mapping.

Comment: @EdwardM.B. how does tomacat will came to know about which servlet is needs to be called on that action.?

Comment: @Krishna The servlet-mapping maps the servlet class to a url-pattern. The webcontainer is the one thats incharge of getting the request, intercepting the url and mapping it to its servlet.

Comment: @EdwardM.B. okey but WebContainer will be getting request but then we have to map that to URl is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the Project name/context path in your url:

```
http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/sayhello
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said you gave the url as  `localhost:8080/sayhello`

Try this url `http://localhost:8080/projectName/sayhello`

Answer (score 0):

> Does your `<Servlet-class>` value resides under any package? If it is,
>   then  give "PackageName.ServletClassName". If it is not the thing try
>   opening with `http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/sayhello` . If it is
>   not the problem try change the port(8080)(right click
>   server->properties->switch location.). Under servers directory right
>   click properties and under server location try change to "use 
>   tomcat installation".Try keeping index.html not only in web-inf but also
>   in web content folder also(if you have index.html file).